# adding unsafe-inline in chrome extension manifest v3

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest, content-security-policy

I'm building a chrome extension and facing a problem related to csp.
I'm using manifest V3

below is my csp

```
 "content_security_policy": { 
      "extension_pages": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/'; object-src 'self'"
    }
```

I'm using alpine.js in my code and wanted to run it.
It was running in v2 but I'm not able to get it working in manifest v3.

Thanks

Comment: It won't work, otherwise it'd be trivial to circumvent the restriction on external code.

Comment: @wOxxOm can this be loaded inside the default_popup when downloaded locally? I'm still getting CSP error mentioning `Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.`

Answer (score 5):

Please see the [Migrating to Manifest V3](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/) (mv3).

Scripts from external domains [are not allowed in mv3](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-overview/#remotely-hosted-code), all scripts must be included into extension package.

`"extension_pages"`: - this policy covers pages in your extension, including HTML files and service workers. These page types are served from the `chrome-extension://` protocol. For instance, a page in your extension is `chrome-extension://<extension-id>/foo.html`.

Therefore `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/` is a wrong source for CSP in mv3. BTW, host-sources like `'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/'` shouldn't be single-quoted in CSP

"*I'm not able to get it working in manifest v3*" is not a technical description of problem. If something fails to work, there should be diagnostic messages in the console.

Comment: Should that work for default_popup too? I tried using "Web_accessible_resource" to inject it inside popup.js loaded from the popup.html, but still get error `Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74402180/how-to-inject-jquery-js-for-chrome-extension-popup-with-manifest-v3

Answer (score 1):

As @granty wrote it's not allowed to use external scripts in Manifest v3.

Even if Alpine.js is included as a local js file it seems that it is using eval(), which is prohibited by manifest v3 as well.
It's allowed in sandboxed pages only (should be explicitly listed in the manifest), but such pages have some restrictions (like disabled extensions API)

```
    "sandbox": {
        "pages": ["awesome_alpine.html"]
    },
```

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/mv3-migration/#content-security-policy
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/sandboxingEval/

Comment: I was getting error for running `vue.js` even though It was stored on local. after adding the `popup.html` to sandbox pages, `vue js` script worked.